# how to drag the window size in wxwidgets?

Tags: c++, c++11, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

In the following image you can see two parts:

[image: Screenshot_20161221_015600.png]

I want to know, what I have to do that I can grap and drag the pipe between those two windows?

```
main ld script    |  constants memory
```

If it cannot be done with wxformbuilder, I would like to know how to code it?

Comment: There's a splitter window control on the "Containers" page in wxFormbuilder.  I think that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @NewPagodi  can you answer the question, please. So I can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the "Containers" page in wxFormbuilder, there is a splitter window control.  It can have 2 subwindows as children and will have a small "sash" area between them that a user can drag to resize them.